# how to add cocos2d V3.3 to the workspace and configure project to use cocos2D V3.3 in iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add cocos2D V3.3 to the workspace and my New project will use cocos2D libraries to develop game. In cocos2D V3.1 there was a installer now there is no installer also. so how can i make it..thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cocos2d is not available as a template installer for Xcode anymore. Instead cocos2d is now bundled with an application called spritebuilder which is available in the Mac Appstore.

You could create a new project in spritebuilder and add your source files and resources from your old project. Its now the most preferred way, as it provides you with automatic cocos2d updates.

If you still want to go the old school way, you'll have to get the zip download from cocos2d [repo](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-swift) in github and add them to your existing project.

The following link explains how to create a new project using spritebuilder.

[Link](https://www.makeschool.com/docs/?source=mgwu#!/cocos2d/1.3/getting-started/getting-started-cocos2d)

Comment: Thanks for reply..it helps a lot. I have one more question for u I wanna use storyBoard for my UI before my game starts. suppose I have UIViewController which has some levels and when user select one level it initiates CCDirector or cocos2d Physics engine. I did this with cocos2D V3.0 but I have now no idea how to do this with cocos2D  V3.3

Comment: Its still the same. You can completely ignore spritebuilder and work just as how you did working.

Comment: Thanks for your quick help johnny

Comment: Downloading the .zip file of the repo won't help as it's not recursive.  Rather use `git clone --recursive https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-swift.git`.  This is useful if you want to install the documentation within Xcode, which you cannot do via the new/preferred SpriteBuilder option.